# Is there a way to filter with selective last change date to view source data in SEU

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle

Is there a way to view records in SEU with certain dates only ? For example I have a source code as below, as we can see it has multiple dates (220318, 220317, 220323) which marks the last change date of that line. Is there any SEU command / CL command / any work around to view only records for '220318'. Maybe like shrink the source to view only for certain dates.

[image]

Any help/suggestion are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press F14 and put your compare option as below:

[image]

Comment: Thank you jiarong, I tried this, it still doesn't show up records only for 22/03/23

Comment: @mrsorrted type X999999 in the first line number of your source to hide them all, then F14 as jiarong shows with "Occurences" to process 2=All then F16

Answer (score 2):

Thank you @Jiarong and @nfgl. Your solution worked.

Here's to sum things up.
first we can open the source in browse mode and exclude all records by putting X999999 on first line number of source to hide them all.

then F14 (Shift + F2) put search date as whatever we want select compare option as 2 and hit F16 (shift + F4).

Below is the output as it would appear if all the above steps are done correctly. P.S. I searched for 220317, and my source had few more records for that date.

[image]